# Would using a VPN, different browser and XprivacyLua prevent a website from remembering me?

Tags: privacy, vpn, xprivacy

Let's say I registered at a website using Google Chrome on my phone, then later on I used a VPN and Firefox restricted through XprivacyLua to access the same website. Would it be able to know that it was me (my) device that accessed it previously? If so, how can I prevent it?

Android 7 | Rooted

Comment: Which website you are talking about? What methods it use to track you (e.g. cookies, tracker scripts, HTTP referrers, user agent info and a long list of fingerprinting parameters, see [here](https://coveryourtracks.eff.org))? What purpose your VPN serves except hiding your public IP? Is it really hiding your public IP (see [this](https://whoer.net/) and [this](https://www.dnsleaktest.com))? What information are you hiding using XPrivacyLua (and from whom)?

Comment: Afaik clearing cookies on your local machine should make the site "forget" you, however modern spyware is widespread and very intelligent. For instance fingerprinting is unique to your device and browser so perhaps changing browsers could help, but an opensource browser like brave which offers fingerprinting protection by default would be your best choice both for convenience and security. If the site logs your IP though, you will have to use a VPN and ensure that you have different IP's each time you connect to that site.

Comment: VPN and XprivacyLua don't have an (or not much) impact on browser fingerprinting. For that the used web browser is more important. See for example this explanation: https://restoreprivacy.com/browser-fingerprinting/ But I am not sure if Firefox for Android is really good in anti-fingerprinting measures. The Windows version of Firefox totally failed in preventing browser fingerprinting (read in the biggest German tech magazine c't).

Comment: @IrfanLatif "Which website you are talking about?" Banks for example. "What methods it use to track you?" I don't know since I can't ask every website I visit, and expect a reply. So let's just assume "every way". "What purpose your VPN serves except hiding your public IP?" Can it serve another purpose? "Is it really hiding your public IP (see this and this)?" I checked and it seems to be hiding it. "What information are you hiding using XPrivacyLua (and from whom)?" https://imgur.com/a/FnIneUv. From the browser.

Comment: @JJrussel the point of my comment is that there are a number of factors which decide what unique information about your device and OS is exposed to the internet. I don't think anyone can give a simple realistic answer to your question. The best way to is perform some online browser tests after taking any measures you think are important. Tests show what information about you is visible to the internet.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Which tests would you recommend?

Comment: The [one](https://coveryourtracks.eff.org) I linked in my first comment is an example. You can find many online.